# laravel jobs not executing - has been attempted too many times or run too long

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel (5.6) is driving me crazy on job queues, cause all of my jobs are returning this error.

```
App\Jobs\PlateFetchData has been attempted too many times or run too long.
The job may have previously timed out.
```

The job doesn't event start to run.

My queue has about 1k entries with the same job but different parameters:

```
foreach($allPlates as $p){
    PlateFetchData::dispatch($p)->onQueue('PlateFetchData');
 }
```

I've already tried with different configurations, like:

```
public $tries   = 1000000;
public $timeout = 30;
```

Or

```
public $tries   = 1;
public $timeout = 30;
```

And running commands like:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=PlateFetchData --tries=1000000
php artisan queue:work --queue=PlateFetchData --tries=1
```

Am I doing something wrong? What else can be causing this problem?